# How to instantiate a struct for testing in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I would like to instantiate a struct in order to test a trait implmentation for that struct. The struct I want to create is [`actix_session::Session`](https://docs.rs/actix-session/latest/actix_session/struct.Session.html), which I do not own. I created a trait and the implemented that trait for `Session` so that I could add functionality.

E.g.

```
pub trait MySession {
    fn set_token(&self, id: String) -> Result<(), Error>;
    ...
}

impl MySession for Session {
    fn set_token(&self, id: String) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.insert(SESSION_TOKEN, id)?;
        Ok(())
    }
    ...
}
```

However, this leaves me with the problem that I cannot make unit tests for the new functionality. I can't figure out any way to create an instance of `Session` for the test, since the Session is created through the action of the Http Response in the actix_session package. I can't create one with `Session{}` notation because `constructor is not visible here due to private fields`.

Is there some way that I can instantiate an empty `Session` for testing purposes?

Comment: Since `Session` is designed to be used as an [extractor](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/), you should probably follow actix-web's [testing](https://actix.rs/docs/testing/) docs to create an `HttpRequest` that you then can use the [`FromRequest`](https://docs.rs/actix-session/latest/actix_session/struct.Session.html#impl-FromRequest) implementation to get your `Session`.